# Can I enter US as visitor on valid H1B for vacation?

Tags: h1b-visas

I have an H1B visa valid for 2 years. I am currently staying and working for the same company that sponsored my visa. I want to visit the US for a 2-week vacation. Can I enter the USA on my H1B visa for vacation?

Comment: Wait, your company got you a H1B visa for working for them in the US, you are currently working for them, but you are not currently in the US?

Comment: @DCTLib - So what is the problem ?

Comment: `Can I enter USA on my H1B visa for vacation` Possible if you can convince the border agent. But if caught, the border agent decides to call your firm,  be prepared for your visa to be cancelled and maybe deported too.

Comment: @DumbCoder This was a request for clarification. The OP wrote that he is "staying" at a company. The combination with this question could imply that either by "visit", he means that he will just take 2 weeks off without crossing the US border, or also that he has a H1B visa and is working for the company that helped him getting it abroad. There could be important information from this question missing, hence the question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Give more details.

Comment: Do you not live in the USA or planning to with your visa?